# PDO inserting zero into my data base instead of the variable content

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to insert data into my database using PDO prepare statement but its inserting zero into my table instead of the variable content

Comment: Please share the code that is doing the inserting and any related code in your project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)